# How do I add a TreeNode ToolTip delay in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, tooltip, treenode

I found that normal tooltips let you add InitialShowDelay. When adding a tooltip in a treeview, I can't seem to edit this delay.

```
TreeNode node;
node.ToolTipText = "Hello";
/* One suggestion was:
 *   ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay
 * Another suggestion was:
 *   toolTip.InitialShowDelay
 * This uses the ToolTip element, which isn't possible in a TreeView
 */
```

I was wondering if it was at all possible to add a TreeNode ToolTip delay without manually drawing each node with DrawNode().

---

**Edit 1:**

As an alternative, I have added a ToolTip control with extra mouse hover event:

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseHover(object sender, TreeNodeMouseHoverEventArgs e) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Node.ToolTipText)) {
        toolTip1.Show(e.Node.ToolTipText, treeView1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your question but the ToolTip.Show method has a duration overload.

I added the value '2000' (time in milliseconds) to your method right after treeView1, so as to satisfy the 'int duration' parameter.

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseHover(object sender, TreeNodeMouseHoverEventArgs e) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Node.ToolTipText)) {
        toolTip1.Show(e.Node.ToolTipText, treeView1, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, there was also an option to give treeview nodestheir own tooltip instead of using the Tooltip control. The first has no delaying options, which is why I switched to the normal tooltip control.